# read messages in android sms from windows

Tags: android, windows, windows-7, android-ndk

I am trying to read SMS (to start off with) that are stored in my Android phone, from a Win 7 machine. I am yet to figure out the API/Interface that I can/should use. I am okay with whatever language it is going to be. Hope someone can point me in the right direction. It need not be as straight as an API. I am okay with some sort of hacks also.

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions I thought of,

1. If your phone is `rooted`, use `adb pull` to get the `SMS Database`, it's in the `Contacts` package
2. Write an Android application with a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for new messages. When a new one comes, wrote down its info to a file. Use `adb` to get this file.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there are any APIs to read messages.

Maybe you can do this.

Write an app which will open a Localsocket and listen. Then through adb you will have to open this same socket from windows 7. You will have to transfer data through this socket.

Comment: Thanks Nandeesh. I was hoping to avoid this.